# How to pass Static Resource String to ConverterParameter in UWP

Tags: c#, xaml, uwp

I m doing an UWP project and I wan't to format a string using a converter and Static resource String because the application is in mulitple languages.

Here is my converter :

```
public class StringFormatConverter : IValueConverter
    {
        public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, string language)
        {
            if (value == null)
                return null;

            if (parameter == null)
                return value;

            return string.Format((string)parameter, value);
        }

        public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter,
            string language)
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }
    }
```

Here the string in my Resource Strings.Xaml file :

```
<x:String x:Key="nbItems">You have {0} items...</x:String>
```

Here the element where I wan't to pass this formatter :

```
<TextBlock  Text="{x:Bind NbItems, Converter={StaticResource StringFormatConverter}, ConverterParameter={StaticResource nbItems}, Mode=OneWay}"/>
```

It's not working but if I do like this it works :

```
  <TextBlock  Text="{x:Bind NbItems, Converter={StaticResource StringFormatConverter}, ConverterParameter='You have {0} items..', Mode=OneWay}"/>
```

The parameters is always null in my converter, why it's not working ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not exactly certain why the parameter is null, however I have come up with a workaround. Move your strings into a Resource file ([see here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/globalizing/put-ui-strings-into-resources)).

[image: Resources file example]

Then change the parameter you pass to your converter to the String Name, like so:

```
<TextBlock  Text="{x:Bind NbItems, Converter={StaticResource StringFormatConverter}, ConverterParameter='FORMAT', Mode=OneWay}" />
```

Finally change your converter to load the the resource using the parameter like so:

```
public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, string language) {
  if (value == null)
    return null;

  var loader = new Windows.ApplicationModel.Resources.ResourceLoader();
  var str = loader.GetString((string)parameter);

  return string.Format(str, value);
}
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I keep this posibility in mind, I wan't to understand why it's not working.

Comment: That's working perfectly thanks, is there a way to pass all Strings I Have to the resw file ?

Comment: Not sure what you mean?

Comment: I have a file with strings like : <x:String x:Key="nbItems">You have {0} items...</x:String> Can I transform it easily to pass it in resw file ?

Comment: The notation for defining a resource looks like so: 

    `<data name="nbItems" xml:space="preserve">
      <value>You have {0} items...</value>
    </data>`

You could use the find/replace functionality in something like Notepad++ to replace `x:String` with `data` and `x:Key` with`name` but you'd still need to wrap your string in `<value>` tags. No real automated way I know of to convert these.
You should also check out the [MultiLingual App Toolkit](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/develop/multilingual-app-toolkit) could help speed up converting strings to other languages

Comment: The reason that the OP's code is not working is because `ConverterParameter` inside `x:Bind` only supports fixed values, `StaticResource` simply won't be evaluated. You can switch to traditional binding for it to work but then you lose the performance boost from `x:Bind`. To me this answer is better than changing the binding.

Comment: @JustinXL Can you show me the other method please ?

Comment: Oh all you need to do is switch your `x:Bind` to `Binding` and change the data context of your page to your VM.